# Vertex Size for more than one vertex

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am pretty sure that the answer to this question is pretty simple, but after googling for several hours in an attempt to find an answer I feel I have to ask someone for help.

I just made my first diagram in Mathematica, however I need different vertex sizes, since the labels are of different lengths:

```
e = {{M1, W1} -> {M1, M2, W1, W2}, {M1, W2} -> {M1, M2, W1, W2}, {M1, 
     W3} -> {M1, M3, W3, W4}, {M1, W4} -> {M1, M3, W3, W4}, {M2, 
     W1} -> {M1, M2, W1, W2}, {M2, W1} -> {M2, M3, W1, W2}, {M2, 
     W2} -> {M1, M2, W1, W2}, {M2, W2} -> {M2, M3, W1, W2}, {M2, 
     W3} -> {M2, M3, W3, W4}, {M2, W4} -> {M2, M3, W3, W4}, {M3, 
     W1} -> {M2, M3, W1, W2}, {M3, W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, W2}, {M3, 
     W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, W3}, {M3, W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, W4}, {M3, 
     W2} -> {M2, M3, W1, W2}, {M3, W2} -> {M3, M4, W1, W2}, {M3, 
     W3} -> {M3, M4, W1, W3}, {M3, W3} -> {M2, M3, W3, W4}, {M3, 
     W3} -> {M1, M3, W3, W4}, {M3, W4} -> {M3, M4, W1, W4}, {M3, 
     W4} -> {M2, M3, W3, W4}, {M3, W4} -> {M1, M3, W3, W4}, {M4, 
     W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, W2}, {M4, W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, W3}, {M4, 
     W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, W4}, {M4, W2} -> {M3, M4, W1, W2}, {M4, 
     W3} -> {M3, M4, W1, W3}, {M4, W4} -> {M3, M4, W1, W4}};

Graph[
 e,
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
 DirectedEdges -> True,
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
 VertexSize -> {0.6,
   {M1, M2, W1, W2} -> 0.9, {M1, M3, W3, W4} -> 
    0.9, {M2, M3, W1, W2} -> 0.9, {M2, M3, W3, W4} -> 
    0.9, {M3, M4, W1, W2} -> 0.9, {M3, M4, W1, W3} -> 
    0.9, {M3, M4, W1, W4} -> 0.9},
 ImageSize -> 1500,
 BaseStyle -> {"Arrowheads" -> .009}
 ]
```

The way I solved it here is pretty inelegant, but I simply do not see how I can assign a vertex size to more than one vertex at a time. Optimally I would like to assign a vertex size according to the Length of the label. Alternatively, I'd be happy to assign the `VertexSize` to a list. In the documentation for `VertexSize`, it is done the same way as I have done it here.

Answer (score 6):

One possibility is to use a [`VertexShapeFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexShapeFunction) whose size depends on the length of the vertex name:

```
Graph[
    e,
    PerformanceGoal->"Quality",
    DirectedEdges->True,
    VertexLabels->Placed["Name",Center],
    ImageSize->1500,
    BaseStyle->{"Arrowheads"->.009},
    VertexShapeFunction->Function@{Disk[#, Length[#2]/8.5], Text[#2,#1]}
]
```

I just used trial and error for the radius.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use rules for setting values for the option `VertexSize` :

```
Graph[e, VertexSize -> {v_ -> .6, v_ /; Length[v] === 4 -> .9},
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", DirectedEdges -> True, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 ImageSize -> 1500, BaseStyle -> {"Arrowheads" -> .009}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Graph[e, VertexSize -> {v_ :> If[Length[v] === 4, .9, .6]},
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", DirectedEdges -> True, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 ImageSize -> 1500, BaseStyle -> {"Arrowheads" -> .009}]
```

> same picture

You might also consider an alternative vertex shape that eliminates the need to set vertex sizes explicitly:

```
Graph[e, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", DirectedEdges -> True, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> (Text[Framed[Style[#2, Black], RoundingRadius -> 10, 
      Background -> LightBlue], #] &), 
 EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[.009], 
 ImageSize -> 1500]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

e = {{M1, W1} -> {M1, M2, W1, W2}, {M1, W2} -> {M1, M2, W1, W2}, {M1, 
     W3} -> {M1, M3, W3, W4}, {M1, W4} -> {M1, M3, W3, W4}, {M2, 
     W1} -> {M1, M2, W1, W2}, {M2, W1} -> {M2, M3, W1, W2}, {M2, 
     W2} -> {M1, M2, W1, W2}, {M2, W2} -> {M2, M3, W1, W2}, {M2, 
     W3} -> {M2, M3, W3, W4}, {M2, W4} -> {M2, M3, W3, W4}, {M3, 
     W1} -> {M2, M3, W1, W2}, {M3, W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, W2}, {M3, 
     W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, W3}, {M3, W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, W4}, {M3, 
     W2} -> {M2, M3, W1, W2}, {M3, W2} -> {M3, M4, W1, W2}, {M3, 
     W3} -> {M3, M4, W1, W3}, {M3, W3} -> {M2, M3, W3, W4}, {M3, 
     W3} -> {M1, M3, W3, W4}, {M3, W4} -> {M3, M4, W1, W4}, {M3, 
     W4} -> {M2, M3, W3, W4}, {M3, W4} -> {M1, M3, W3, W4}, {M4, 
     W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, W2}, {M4, W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, W3}, {M4, 
     W1} -> {M3, M4, W1, W4}, {M4, W2} -> {M3, M4, W1, W2}, {M4, 
     W3} -> {M3, M4, W1, W3}, {M4, W4} -> {M3, M4, W1, W4}};

vLong = Cases[e, _List?(Length[#] > 2 &), {2}] // Union;

Graph[e, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
 DirectedEdges -> True,
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
 VertexSize -> Flatten[{0.6, Thread[vLong -> 0.9]}],
 ImageSize -> 1500,
 BaseStyle -> {"Arrowheads" -> 0.009}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have one last question I learned how I can change the filling of the vertices and I also learnt how I can change the border color of the vertices. But somehow I can't change both. The problem seems to be similar: 
The former would be changed by VertexStyle -> White the latter by VertexStyle -> {EdgeForm[White] but combining both is impossible. I'd like to see if that would not allow me to make the diagram more compact.

Comment: Use either `VertexStyle -> Directive[White, EdgeForm[White]]` or `VertexStyle -> {{White, EdgeForm[White]}}`

Comment: okay sorry! I thought I had tried that but it didn't work now I copy pasted it from your response and it works like a charm thank you so much!